# Открытие изображений как ВКонтакте

Tags: jquery-ui, css, javascript

Здравствуйте.

Требуется модальное окно с изображением, всплывающее по клику на превью, и **имеющее свою уникальную ссылку** (если пользователь жмёт на неё - открывается та же страница с уже загруженным модальным окном). Так реализован просмотр изображений ВКонтакте.

Может есть где нибудь готовые библиотеки, дающие этот функционал?

Либо не обязательно именно изображения, хотя бы просто библиотека для создания модальных окон, которые могут открываться и по ссылкам.

Заранее большое спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте после вывода окошка с изображением динамически JavaScript'ом менять URL. Вот пример использования pushState и replaceState:

```
// эмуляция перехода на страничку "/page2.html" без перезагрузки странички 
window.history.pushState("object or string", "Title", "/page2.html"); 
// замена текущего URL на "/page3.html" 
window.history.replaceState("object or string", "Title", "/page3.html");
```

[Подробнее тут](http://web.izjum.com/url-changing-without-page-reloading)

Answer (score 0):

[fancybox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) очень советую, чудесная вещь. А вообще таких плагинов море, на любой вкус.

Comment: Вы видимо плохо прочитали вопрос. Картинки открываются, отлично, но (!) URL остаётся неизменным.

Answer (score 0):

у remodal добавляется хэш на конце url, ссылка с нужным хэш-тегом откроет модальное окно